# Imported java files is not being called

Tags: java, debugging, jndi

I am facing problem as the actual imported java file is not being called. Please have a look of my code :-

```
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    .....
   public class ABC{
   .....
  1.      Context lContext = null;
  2.        ObjectDataSourceFactory lSource = null;
  3.      try
  4.       {
  5.           lContext = new InitialContext();
  6.           lSource = ((ObjectDataSourceFactory)lContext.lookup(....));
     }
        catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
```

The Problem I am facing here is : when flow control goes into line number 6. it calls the "lookup method" from "SelectorContext.java" but not from "InitialContext.java", I have found this with the help of DEBUGGING mode in eclipse . As a result it cannot find the proper JNDI and gives exception.
FYI..
My code is running on Tomcat6.
I have set the classpath of jar files from my JRE1.6 and so the JDK.

Can someone please suggest me -
  how can I know from which JAR this "SelectorContext.java" is being called and how to make it to Look into the InitialContext.class which is present inside RT.JAR, if I am not wrong  ?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not correct. SelectorContext is one of the JNDI implementations of the tomcat.

There is an option to use external JNDI context by setting java.naming.factory.initial as system variable. This is set by Tomcat (javaURLContextFactory) to provide it's own JNDI services.

When you call new InitialContext(), JVM sees if there is user provided naming factory, and if it is available, JVM calls initialFactory.getInitialContext to get the custom JNDI implementation and makes this default and all the method calls to context is inturn routed to custom implementation.

In your case, call to SelectorContext is right, see if you have the required configuration in place to have the resource in JNDI.